# permissions issue when trying to update npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I tried to update to the latest version of npm and got this error? Anyone ever have a permission error with npm before? I'm stuck as to how to fix it.

```
marshalls-MacBook-Air:Desktop marshall$ npm install npm@latest -g
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/Cellar/node/11.9.0/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/Cellar/node/11.9.0/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.9.0/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.9.0/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.9.0/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.9.0/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/marshall/.npm/_logs/2019-09-24T17_21_36_708Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Use `sudo` before the command.

Answer (score 2):

you need permission :

```
sudo npm install npm@latest -g
```

then put your password